# Granger Causality Python

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistical-significance, python, granger-causality

I am very news to statistics and have been learning some machine learning in one of my college degree modules. I am just looking for some information. I have a couple of time-series data sets that I am trying to explore correlation and causations in the data. For my example, I have to two series, one is a series of ints that represent the volume in a currency market on each given day. The second is a count of the count number of posts on an online forum in regards to a given currency. From some research journals, I have read online the data sets are transformed to the respective Z-scores. In this case, the market volume Z-scores is calculated on the day to day performance percentage change and Z-scores are calculated for the forum activity count. Using these scores Granger causality is tested using `statsmodels` python library where X(Volume score) Granger causes Y(Forum activity scores). This example gives a result a `P-value: 0.9939258898505543` with a lag of `2`. This p-value of allows me to accept the null for X = f(Y), but my issue is the p-value seems very high which I was not expecting. This has to lead to me wondering does use Z-scores skew the results.  My Question is: Is using Z-scores to calculate granger casualty skew results and is this the correct approach to take.

Results from these tests will be used for feature selection in a machine learning model. Sorry if this is a very amateur question, but my time is very limited at the moment due to college assignments. I am fully intending to delve into learning statistics over the summer holidays.  Thanks for any help much appreciated.